# Get the import filename?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I've got a Triggered/File Drop watching a folder for wildcard filename (incoming-*.csv).  The first step of my automation is an import that is acting upon "%%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%%".  Everything's working great.

The automation brings in the file into a table. It increments a counter and then takes the imported content plus the incremented counter and puts them into a larger table and then sends me a summary of all the entries in the larger table. 
(audience 320 has x mailable, audience 321 has x mailable, etc.)

However, then I have to manually or mentally map 320 = "incoming-20170601_highlyengaged.csv", "321 = incoming-20170601_recentpurchaser.csv".

Is there any other method or mechanism that I might be able to use to grab the filename and get it into a DE for later use?

Unfortunately, "select %%FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER%% as label..." isn't valid query code.

Comment: what is the logic for highly engaged/ recent purchaser?? Are these value passed in the import or you have to determine them?

Comment: Those were just segmentation examples.  I do not have the data in ExactTarget necessary to do the segmentation myself within the tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a thorough investigation, I have been told with finality that this is NOT something that can be done by the end user.... BUT it is something that is possible for them to build as a 'custom report'.

So, unless you want to fork over the extra cash and have them build something on the backend for you, you will likely need to utilize something like the solution @MartyC. provided.

The synopsis on why it is not accessible is that there are certain databases that are too 'sensitive' (for lack of a better term) to be accessible to any user as they could potentially make the whole environment unstable - and one of those locations is where the import file name is stored. It is viewable in a few places, for instance the import alert email sent out to the EU - but it cannot be called directly by the user.

Comment: Thanks.  That was my suspicion, but I had hoped I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm oversimplifying but what you're describing sounds like a use case for a "header" table. Think `Opportunity`-`OpportunityLineItem` or `Order`-`OrderItem`.

Basically, you need a simple table that stores one record for every qualifying file, recording the following.

- **Audience ID** — This is the 320, 321, etc. you used in your examples
- **Import Filename** — This is the "incoming-20170601_highlyengaged.csv", "incoming-20170601_recentpurchaser.csv" you used in your examples

Or, if you don't want to create an entirely separate table, you can normalize the data structure and simply add **Import Filename** to the table that contains all of the entries from each CSV file. This results in a ton of duplicate data, but if you find the performance/monetary cost to be worth the development tradeoff this should meet your needs.

Comment: Yep, I have that.  I have a separate automated trigger just to pick up that little file and retroactively label the existing imported audiences.  It's just an extra step that I was trying to eliminate.

Comment: @Marty C - although you did not quite answer the question, you provided good insight and a viable alternative, plus I certainly don't want the bounty to go to waste.

Comment: I realize that this is an old question, but I am unable to understand how to get the Import Filename added to the simple table?  How can I store the FILENAME_FROM_TRIGGER in a DE somewhere?

Comment: @EricB. you have to do that before the file reaches Salesforce. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65035008/2415733) for adding a new column to an existing CSV file with Python is one example.

Comment: @MartyC. Thanks - that's what I had suspected but was hoping to be able to use a Script block or something to get the Trigger Filename.  Sadly, I wasn't able to figure out any creative solution which didn't include modifying the file.